# "Subjective complement and objective complement"

Tags: grammar, difference, usage, complements

What is the difference between "subjective complement" and "objective complement"?

How can I recognize them in the sentences?

Is there any special rule for them?

Do they use after special verbs? If yes which verbs?

Comment: http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_complement.htm for object, http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subject_complement.htm for subject. A little homework helps :)